# Joomla - Wrong url path from google results

Tags: url, joomla

I have a strange problem in one Joomla website.
If i access from homepage and then navigate into the site it works correct, but if i go in some internal page from google results it shows uncorrect page layout, because the url is not correct.

This is the correct url 
[Correct page from homepage](http://www.winetsolutions.it/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=20&Itemid=127&lang=en)

and this the uncorrect url that Google finds [Uncorrect page from Google](http://www.winetsolutions.it/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=7%3areferenze&catid=11&Itemid=104&lang=en)

in this second page is showed rating module (that i never used) instead of an article, as you can see in links.

Someone can help me?

EDIT: I'm using Joomla 2.5 version. Every menu item is category blog type, and must show all articles of one category. Each category have 2 articles. In the uncorrect link seems that it access to single article, adding the rating that i have hidden in each article

Comment: You may check your recent installed modules/ plugins/ widgets for solving this, more important if you have installed any widgets related to URL/PATH, check that now..

Comment: This could be a problem of you internal structure. It seems that the article is accessible multiple times. Please check that after you checked the hints form the previous comment.

Comment: @FredFloete, how to prevent the multi-accessibility of an article?

Comment: @Prijm.com, i checked and i haven't anything about URL/PATH, i used default Joomla content + GoogleMap module, a scroller module and K2 module

Comment: @alexLapi, istanbailey answered it alread. Make sure that all articles are assinged to a menu. Disable all categories,... which are not used by the template elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using?
if you can turn on SEF option in the global settings in joomla admin. Then you need to make sure all your articles are in menus. then if you link them on different pages it should keep the url the same.
The way you have it at the moment with all the x=123&... get params pages will show for what ever ids you change the menu to.

Comment: I'm using Joomla 2.5 version. If i turn on SEF option, my menu not work more, because can't find other page. I'll edit now my question for put more informations

Comment: After changing the SEF option please clear the cache of Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing an uncorrect layout is the two different Itemid parameters (the right url has 127 while the wrong one has 104). The rest of the difference in the urls will be ignored by Joomla.

Solution: Find your menu item with id 104 (look at the menu ids on the right of the menu items view), then check which modules appear on the page from there. There may be modules in non-visible positions.

One of these modules is publishing the links with the wrong ids. If it's a Joomla core (like a search module) you can usually force the Itemid either in the module or in the component's configuration.  Else you need to fixsome third party code.

Only once you have solved the multiple-itemid should you turn on SEF, otherwise you'd get the same problem only more difficult to trace.

sh404 could help you with this, I'd give it a try on a test site to see if it gets you out of trouble faster.